# My activity closes down when i cancel or accept bluetooth enable request?

Tags: android, start-activity

There is no error in the logcat just the current activity closes down and previous activity opens.

Here is the code where am puttin bluetooth enabling request:

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (!(bluetooth.isEnabled())) {
                   Log.e("blue",""+"not working");
                   status = "Bluetooth is not Enabled.";
                   Toast.makeText(AddUser.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);

                }
                else
                {

                    scand();
                }

           }



    });
```

Here is onactivityresult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println(resultCode);
    Log.e("resultblue",""+resultCode);
    if (resultCode ==  RESULT_CANCELED) {


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

             Toast.makeText(AddUser.this, "Error Enabling bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } else {

            scand();
    }



}
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: does you have any log entries from the bluethoot intent reciever? Are you developing on emultor?

Comment: I just found out that i had nohistory enabled for the activity in the manifest file. so when i was starting the startactivity for result, te current activity was being destroyed. i am such a fool. :'(. That was the real problem right?

Comment: thank you for asking this. You just saved me a lot of time. I am just as much a fool :)